# SwiftUI - Embedded UITextField invokes the shouldChangeCharacters delegate method for suggested text

Tags: swift, uitextfield, swiftui, uitextfielddelegate, uiviewrepresentable

I'm using `UIViewRepresentable` to wrap a `UITextField` in order to create a `TextField` view for SwiftUI which is more fully featured than the currently built-in one. The `Coordinator` class is of course the delegate of the `UITextField`. The delegate method `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` is getting called when the user types a character (as it should), but also when an autocorrect suggestion comes up. As far as I know this is not normal `UITextField` behavior, and it's very troublesome. Is this because the text field is embedded in a SwiftUI view hierarchy?

Comment: Please add your code here for us to see.

Comment: "when an autocorrect suggestion comes up" – as in, when the user chooses to accept the autocorrect suggestion? Or is this when the user chooses a word from the 3-option suggestions bar above the keyboard? In either of those situations this would be expected behaviour afaik.

Comment: What happens is that I type two letters, but the delegate method is run three times. The first time it is run with the first letter I typed “A”, the second time with the two letter word I’ve typed “Ab”, and then a third time with the suggested replacement word “An”. This happens immediately after I type “b” - I do not choose the suggestion, nor implicitly accept it by typing a space, nothing...